# preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing )

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

The error is:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 16 in /home/siteraja/public_html/ar/wp-content/plugins/hide_my_wp/lib/mute-screamer/libraries/IDS/Monitor.php on line 312
>   And here's the code at line 227:

```
  // check if this field is part of the exceptions
        if (is_array($this->exceptions)) {
            foreach($this->exceptions as $exception) {
                $matches = array();
                $reg = '/'.str_replace('%','[A-Za-z0-9_-]*', str_replace('.','\.',$exception)).'/i';
                if (preg_match($reg, $key))
                    return false;


            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your original string along with expected output

Comment: Try `$reg = '/'.str_replace('%','[A-Za-z0-9_-]*', preg_quote($exception)).'/i';`

Comment: By that he means post the contents of `$this->exception` or `$this->exceptions` so we can see what is being passed into the `$reg` calculation

Comment: Your exception string doesn't, by any chance, contain `'` or `/` characters does it?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable to initialize a regex pattern. Without knowing what characters there may be inside that string, you cannot be sure the regex syntax will be correct. To eliminate this risk, use `preg_quote` that will escape (=add `\`) in front of each special character. So, replace

```
$reg = '/'.str_replace('%','[A-Za-z0-9_-]*', str_replace('.','\.',$exception)).'/i';
```

with

```
$reg = '/'.str_replace('%','[A-Za-z0-9_-]*', preg_quote($exception)).'/i';
```

Also please note you only declare `$matches = array();`, but you are not using it, but that is perhaps just because you do not show the whole code.